# Cloud Scheduler Page Access Issue - Shared project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-scheduler

The manager holds the account that provides billing to the said project, now I cannot go to [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) page due to my account not having a billing setup, therefore my workaround is to manually input the link directly to the page like this
[https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler?project={PROJECT_ID}](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler?project=%7BPROJECT_ID%7D)
but now it no longer work and throwing error page. Supposedly I am able to access **"Cloud Scheduler"** page regardless if the account I use does not have a billing setup since the billing was already made by other account on this shared the project right? Is anyone having the same issue as of this date? Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Add a billing account?

Comment: You have no project selected in the screenshot you shared, that might be a problem. What do you mean by `The manager holds the account that provides billing to the said project`? If this is all setup, why can't this manager provide you access to the project with billing setup, since it's shared?

Comment: @RafaelLemos the project is already provided in the url, also even after selecting the project it will still throw the error and no project will be indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the billing card that being used is no longer valid or having some issue.

[image]